Help finding this car keyless fob component
It is likely fairly obvious to some, but I cannot seem to find any information regarding the part in the picture, what does it do? And how does it work? Some keyless fob have it in conjunction with an RF transmitter chip, while other fobs don't have the component and only an RF transmitter. Why the discrepancy?



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why the discrepancy? ... different design
